# How to make cards appear one after another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Div, Panel, Button, PanelHeader } from "@vkontakte/vkui"
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'

const Home = ({ id, go, sortUsersData }) => {

    const dataArray = sortUsersData;

    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState()

    const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete) => {
        console.log('removing: ' + nameToDelete)
        setLastDirection(direction)
    }

    const outOfFrame = (name) => {
        console.log(name + ' left the screen!');
    }

    return (
        <Panel id={id}>
            <PanelHeader>Title</PanelHeader>
            <Div>
                <div className='cardContainer'>
                    {
                        dataArray.map((character) =>
                            <TinderCard className="swipe" key={character.first_name} onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, character.first_name)} onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(character.name)} preventSwipe={["up", "down"]}>
                                <div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + character.image + ")" }} className="card">
                                    <h3 class="name">{character.first_name}</h3>
                                    <h2 class="age">{character.distance} лет</h2>
                                    <h1 class="bio">{character.bio}</h1>
                                </div>
                            </TinderCard>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
                {lastDirection ? <h2 className="infoText">You swiped {lastDirection}</h2> : <h2 className="infoText"/>}
            </Div>
        </Panel>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

And when I run it, I see all the cards, but I wanna know how I can make them appear in order. When I swipe 1 card from the screen another one will be loaded. I wanna do this because when I have a really big array, it starts to work very slowly.

Thanks!!

Comment: what do you mean by "in order"?  in order of what?

Comment: if you are looking to order the card by distance just sort the `dataArray`.

Comment: @DanO One after another. One swiped, next appeared. And so on until they run out

Comment: Instead of rendering an array of cards, you can just render one card. Use a state to keep track of the index of the current card. For example, when the state is `3`, then you render the card for `dataArray[3]`. You can update the state on the event handlers for swipes or any other actions you want.

Comment: @gzcz “Use state to track the index of the current map.” - Could you give me an example code, please. Because I'm new to javascript